# Can a NFC TAG contain a deeplink?

Tags: android, nfc, deeplink

It's possible to add a deeplink in web page to either call an installed application or redirect the user to the store if the target app is not installed.
The link will be in the form of:

```
<a href=´intent://www.myweb.com/service?datas="....."#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.my.example;end´>My Service</a>
```

Is it possible to put this kind of deeplink in a NFC tag and get the same behavior i.e., I suppose, open the web browser?

**EDIT**
So I tried with [NFC tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc), with the feature `personnalized URL/URI` , where I wrote

```
intent://www.myweb.com/service?datas="myData"#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.my.example;end
```

But When I then read it, NFC service only tells me that a new tag has been added but not interpret it to start my app. So `intent:....` seems not to be something which causes an action.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Have you tried to put the link on a tag?

Comment: @MichaelRoland No I didn't try because I currently don't have tag with enough memory to store it. I just wanted to know if it's supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, you can store just any URL you like on an NFC tag.

Comment: @MichaelRoland, ok Thanks a lot I'm going to find needed NFC Tag

Comment: @MichaelRoland Sorry but I tried and it seems not working. I used [NFC Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc) and tried with `personnalized URL/URI`. But when I then read it, NFC service only tells me that a new tag has been added but doesn't interpret it.

Comment: Well, obviously when you want your app to be triggered by the URL, you have to make the app listen for that URL with an appropriate NDEF_DISCOVERED intent filter. Since you mentioned that the URL works from a webdite, I assumed you already had such an intent filter that you would just need to extend with the new action.

Comment: @MichaelRoland The main interest of a deeplink is that it can a dedicated application launch but can alos rediret the user to Google Play to download it if it doesn't the app already installed. This is this last capability which is very interesting for me but anyway, even with the app installed `intent:...` seems to able to trig any action at the moment in Android.

Comment: Okay then. In that case you would want two records on the tag, the first being the URL that you already have and the second an android application record (AAR) with the package name of your app.

Comment: @MichaelRoland ok, I didn't know this kind of record. But in fact, I was exploring this possibility because up to now, I successfully used 'normal' url read from QRCode. And strangely, when I put this working url in a NFC tag, it doesn't work. For a reason I don't understand, Android browser doesn't interpret the returned deeplink. That works from QRCode and that doesn't work from NFC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159233/how-to-produce-a-deeplink-action-from-a-web-redirection?noredirect=1#comment71483696_42159233